# how to set dynamic attribute in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, attributes

In Html:

```
<input class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="value" #muInput/>
<button (click)="onSetAttribute()"> set</button>`
```

In this:

```
`@ViewChild('muInput') muInput: ElementRef; `
```

`public seperator : string   onSetAttribute() {` if(this.seperator  ) {
this.muInput.nativeElement.setAttribute('mask' , this.seperator); this.muInput.nativeElement.setAttribute('thousandSeparator' , ',');`
}}

**I want to click on the button set a mask attribute to input this my code but is not working**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
  <input class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="value" #muInput  [attr.mask]="mask" />
   <button (click)="changeMask()"> set</button>
```

In your component ts file, you should declare a class attribute `mask`, give it  default value of w/e you want then:

```
changeMask() { this.mask = 'separator.2' // w/e value }
```

same thing for `thousandSeparator` attribute.

Comment: I want to set this attribute when there is a separator value, not always

Comment: @mehdi how are you detecting there's a separator value?

Comment: I have a property called seperator using this to determine

Answer (score 0):

import {  Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
Use Renderer2 setattribute function

```
 constructor ( private _renderer: Renderer2) {  }



onSetAttribute() {
this._renderer.setAttribute(this.muInput.nativeElement,'mask' , 'separator.2');
this._renderer.setAttribute(this.muInput.nativeElement,'thousandSeparator' , ',');

}
```

Comment: what error are you facing?This is just to show you that you can use renderer2 and apart from that you can also add your separator logic

Comment: No error but the separator does not work I expect 3 digits to separate 3 digits of numbers but this does not happen

Comment: what is the expected output ? So an number is entered 1000 you want it to displayed as 1,000

Comment: Please mention the desired input and output clearly